# Replace until all occurrences are removed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following strings:

```
",||||||||||||||"
",|||||a|||||,|"
```

**I would like to achieve** that all occurrences of `",|"` are replaced with `",,"`

The output should be the following:

```
",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"
",,,,,,a|||||,,"
```

**When I run `.gsub(',|', ',,')` on the strings I get not the desired output.**

```
",,|||||||||||||"
",,||||a|||||,,"
```

That's because it does not run `gsub` several times.
Is there a similar method that runs recursively.

Comment: We need more of a description here. Are you saying when you see a comma followed by a pipe, replace it with commas until you see a non comma/pipe combo?

Comment: This is pure Ruby, nothing to do with Rails.

Comment: @Anthony you are correct! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an old library of mine. This method iterates until the block output is equal to its input :

```
def loop_until_convergence(x)
  x = yield(previous = x) until previous == x
  x
end

puts loop_until_convergence(',||||||||||||||') { |s| s.gsub(',|', ',,') }
# ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"
puts loop_until_convergence(',|||||a|||||,|') { |s| s.gsub(',|', ',,') }
# ",,,,,,a|||||,,"
```

As a bonus, you can calculate a square root in [very few iterations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsIteration.html) :

```
def root(n)
  loop_until_convergence(1) { |x| 0.5 * (x + n / x) }
end

p root(2)
# 1.414213562373095
p root(3)
# 1.7320508075688772
```

Comment: `loop_until_convergence` is quite cool. Out of curiosity, I found that it takes only `6` steps with the Taylor's expansion to compute `root(2)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: As far as I can tell, Newton's iteration requires only 5 steps. `1` doesn't really count, does it?

Comment: Right, 5 steps with @Newton's method.

Answer (score 8):

A regular expression matches can not overlap. Since matches are what is used for replacement, you can't do it that way. Here's two workarounds:

```
str = ",|||||a|||||,|"
while str.gsub!(/,\|/, ',,'); end

str = ",|||||a|||||,|"
str.gsub!(/,(\|+)/) { "," * ($1.length + 1) }
```

Comment: Nice. If you want to see the intermediate steps : `puts str while str.gsub!(/,\|/, ',,')`

Comment: Nice one. I would have only given #2 (or, at minimum, made it #1) as it requires just a single pass. Did you mean to change `gsub!` to `gsub` in #2 (after a copy-and-paste, perhaps) as the OP evidently does not want to mutate the string. Note that #1 also mutates the string, but you can't make the same change there because it relies on `gsub!` returning `nil` when no change is made. Moreover, #1 doesn't return the modified `str`, so if it's wrapped in a method you might need `str` as a last line. I see you're approaching the century mark on rep.

Answer (score 5):

```
smoke_weed_every_day = lambda do |piper|
  commatosed = piper.gsub(',|', ',,')
  commatosed == piper ? piper : smoke_weed_every_day.(commatosed)
end

smoke_weed_every_day.(",||||||||||||||") # => ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"
smoke_weed_every_day.(",|||||a|||||,|")  # => ",,,,,,a|||||,,"
```

Comment: very clever solution

Answer (score 0):

As with @Amandan's second solution there is no need to iterate until no further changes are made.

```
COMMA = ','
PIPE  = '|'

def replace_pipes_after_comma(str)
  run = false
  str.gsub(/./) do |s|
    case s
    when PIPE
      run ? COMMA : PIPE    
    when COMMA
      run = true
      COMMA
    else
      run = false
      s
    end
  end
end

replace_pipes_after_comma ",||||||||||||||"
  #=>                     ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,," 
replace_pipes_after_comma ",|||||a|||||,|"
  #=>                     ",,,,,,a|||||,,"
```